For which associative algebras irreps can be distinguished by the action of the center?
Let $A$ be an associative algebra over an algebraically closed field $k$ and let $Z$ be the center of $A$. It is well known that if $V$ is an irreducible representation, then $Z$ acts on $V$ via some character, that is, for $z \in Z$, $v \in V$ we have $z\cdot v = \chi_V(z) v$ for some character $\chi_V \colon Z \to k$, called the central character of $V$.
In the following cases non-isomorphic finite-dimensional irreps of $A$ induce non-isomorphic characters of $Z$:

Universal enveloping algebras of semisimple Lie algebras. This is a nontrivial statement which requires Harish-Chandra isomorphism and a fair bit of representation theory of Lie algebras, see for example Bourbaki "Lie groups and Lie algebras" VIII.8.5.Cor2.

Semisimple finite-dimensional algebras. This follows from the classification of semisimple finite-dimensional algebras, they are products of matrix algebras. Essentially, irreps correspond to simple factors, and the center has one copy of $k$ for each factor.

Commutative algebras — trivially.


Are there algebras for which this property does not hold? I suspect yes, otherwise we wouldn't need the complicated theory for Lie-algebraic case, but the example eludes me at the moment. Can the algebras with this property be characterized in some way? Maybe in characteristic $0$?

An easy counterexample is the ring $A=\begin{pmatrix}k&k\\0&k\end{pmatrix}$ of upper triangular $2\times2$ matrices over a field $k$.
$A$ has two nonisomorphic one-dimensional simple modules: namely, the quotients by the ideals $\begin{pmatrix}k&k\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0&k\\0&k\end{pmatrix}$, but the centre of $A$ is isomorphic to $k$ and acts in the same way on both simple modules.
